# Node.js connectivity to Oracle DB

Tags: node.js, cloud-foundry

I have NODE.JS app hosted on Pivotal Cloud Foundry. All this APP does is connect to ORACLE DB and fetch the data which user request from the Front End APP built on ANGULAR.

I have all the required NPM Modules for the NODE.JS. My APP requires ORACLE instant client which is required to connect to ORACLE DB along with npm-oracledb

I have just placed the instant_client libraries under npm_modules of my code.

But seems like it is unable to hit the ORACLE DB. And I think this is due to not pointing the Instant Client libraries correctly.

Could someone please let me know how can I point the instant client library to my code so that it can connect to ORACLE DB.

Appreciate your time experts...

I did run quick API to hit the APP hosted on Cloud Foundry, it is executing until it gets timeout and I think this is due to unable to establish the DB connection

manifest.yml file:

```
---
applications:
- name: node-app
  command: node server.js
  memory: 512M
  disk_quota: 1024M
  instances: 1
  buildpack: nodejs_buildpack
  env:
   LD_LIBRARY_PATH: node_modules/
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? Where did you get the idea to put the Instant Client in the node_modules directory? What operating system are you using? What versions of node-oracledb and the Instant Client are you using? Have you seen this part of the install doc? https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html#334-install-the-free-oracle-instant-client-basic-zip-file

Comment: Perhaps helpful -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52217238/node-js-app-over-cloud-foundry-failing-as-node-oracledb-dep-is-not-getting-downl

Comment: LD_LIBRARY_PATH is a system environment variable and needs to be set before the process that uses it starts.  Is manifest.yml the appropriate place, or is that read after the Node.js process begins?